# Cannot open file at line 27805

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a huge problem I cannot get my head around, basically when accessing my android database after approximately 130 reads from the database it throws this into the logcat and the activity ends. The database is reading perfectly up until this point and cannot see a reason why it fails at this point every time.

`09-04 16:45:31.754: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) cannot open file at line 27805 of [9491ba7d73]
09-04 16:45:31.754: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) os_unix.c:27805: (24) open(/data/data/com.boltgames.dev.cricketone/databases) - 
09-04 16:45:31.758: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
09-04 16:45:31.758: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) os_unix.c:30046: (24) open(/data/data/com.boltgames.dev.cricketone/databases/Student.db-journal) - 
09-04 16:45:31.758: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
09-04 16:45:31.758: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) os_unix.c:30046: (24) open(/data/data/com.boltgames.dev.cricketone/databases/Student.db-journal) - 
09-04 16:45:31.758: E/SQLiteLog(4213): (14) statement aborts at 37: [SELECT DISTINCT _id, NAME, SURNAME, AGE, STAMINA, FITNESS, BOWLINGSKILL, BATTINGSKILL, OVERS, MAIDENS, BWLRUNS, WICKETS, ECONOMY, STRIKERATE, INNS, NOTOUT, BATRUNS, FIFTY, HUNDRED, FOU
09-04 16:45:31.759: E/SQLiteQuery(4213): exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: SELECT DISTINCT _id, NAME, SURNAME, AGE, STAMINA, FITNESS, BOWLINGSKILL, BATTINGSKILL, OVERS, MAIDENS, BWLRUNS, WICKETS, ECONOMY, STRIKERATE, INNS, NOTOUT, BATRUNS, FIFTY, HUNDRED, FOURS, SIXES, DUCKS, CURBALLS, CURRUNS, CURFOURS, CURSIXES FROM Langley
09-04 16:45:31.759: D/AndroidRuntime(4213): Shutting down VM
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213): Process: com.boltgames.dev.cricketone, PID: 4213
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.DatabaseHelper.getAllRows(DatabaseHelper.java:124)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Play.SetData(Play.java:149)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Play.SetPlayers(Play.java:134)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Play.PlayOneRun(Play.java:277)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.boltgames.dev.cricketlife.Play$1.onClick(Play.java:249)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-04 16:45:31.760: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

Here is my access code to the database

```
cursor = mydb.getAllRows(gamemanager.hometeam);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] fromfieldnames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3,
            DatabaseHelper.COL_23, DatabaseHelper.COL_24};
    int[] toviewids = new int[]{R.id.scorecplayer, R.id.scorecsur, R.id.scorecballs, R.id.scorecruns};
    mycursoradaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.scorecardbat,
            cursor, fromfieldnames, toviewids);
    batting.setAdapter(mycursoradaptor);
    totruns.setText(Long.toString(totalruns));
    ballComplete = true;
    oneballnorun.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Please help :(

M.

Edit: - Added code of database script

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Return all data in database
    String where = null;
    cursor = db.query(true, teamname, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    Log.i("Success2", "Data is accessed");
    if (cursor != null){
        Log.i("Cursor3", cursor.toString());
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    }
    if(cursor == null){
        Log.i("Error!!!", "No Data!");
    }
    return cursor;
```

Comment: Forgive me but why the downvote?

Comment: 'after approximately 130 reads'. What do you consider 'a read'?

Comment: ok, so for example I run the above script every time a "ball" is played. After between approx. 139 and 146 runs of the script the application fails. I have done some debugging up to now and found no errors up until where the cursor is being created. I will add the code above for you. So pretty much runs fine then after the above time the cursor or db become corrupt somehow

Comment: As `cursor` should be closed (db too), I miss `Cursor cursor = d b.query(...)` to ensure clear code.

Comment: Script? This is java code isn't it? What is the connection between the cursor used in the first code block and the second? Are you ever closing a cursor after use?

Comment: Fixed :) Thank you for your help, I closed the cursor each time I updated it from the db side and all is stable so far thank you for your help with this to both of you and yes sorry green this is Java

Comment: 'I closed the cursor each time I updated it from the db'. Well that was not the case. I think you ment 'I never closed the cursor when i updated from db. But now that i do all works fine.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mydb.cursor.close();
    Log.i("Success1", "Access Started");
    try {
        cursor = mydb.getAllRows(gamemanager.hometeam);
    }catch (Throwable ex) {
        Log.i("Error", "Maybe retrying i dont know");
    }
    Log.i("Success!4", "Cursor is Active!" );
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    Log.i("Success!5", "Cursor is being managed");
    String[] fromfieldnames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3,
            DatabaseHelper.COL_23, DatabaseHelper.COL_24};
    Log.i("Success6", "Stage1");
    int[] toviewids = new int[]{R.id.scorecplayer, R.id.scorecsur, R.id.scorecballs, R.id.scorecruns};
    Log.i("Success7", "Stage2");
    mycursoradaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.scorecardbat,
            cursor, fromfieldnames, toviewids);
    Log.i("Success8", "Stage3");
    batting.setAdapter(mycursoradaptor);
    Log.i("Success9", "Stage4");
```

Comment: Inserted the close at the start of the function and as you can see lots of debugging haha probably looks a mess to the more professional eyes :)